# T4MVC and Resharper Navigation

Tags: resharper, t4mvc

I frequently use Resharper's 'Go to Declaration' (ctrl + b in the Resharper Default Keymapping) keyboard shortcut to help with navigation within VS2010.  Before I included a reference to T4MVC in my application, I would use "string refrences" and Resharper would know where I 'meant' to go.

For example:

```
@Html.Partial("_Continents" )
```

When I would use ctrl+b on the string `"_Continents"`, Resharper knew I wanted to go to the partial view named _Continents.cshtml.

Since I have started using T4MVC, the same snippet above could be written:

```
@Html.Partial( MVC.CascadingDropDownLists.DropDownAjaxPost.Views._Continents )
```

When I use ctrl+b on `_Continents`, instead of taking me to the partial view, it takes me to the T4MVC generated code.

Is there any way to keep T4MVC in the project (I *really* like the strongly typed feel and intellisense support), while restoring the original navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, ReSharper's MVC navigation works only on constants.
If T4MVC will generate consts instead of readonly fields - it should works.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small Visual Studio macro to help with this. It has issues, but it is far better than nothing IMO. It replaces F12, so you don't have to use a separate function for each.

I've posted it here:

[Visual Studio macro to navigate to T4MVC link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100124/visual-studio-macro-to-navigate-to-t4mvc-link)